# Brief Website Outages: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED | Unable to open TCP socket

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, tcp

~1 out of 25 times when I try to connect to my website, I get the response ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, although the issue quickly corrects itself and I am able to access the site within a second. I use pingdom to monitor the site, and the logs show "Connection refused HTTP CRITICAL - Unable to open TCP socket".

I can't seem to figure out how to correct this error and I was looking for some guidance on how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake on my part - the answer was found when I noticed the PID for nginx was constantly changing, which led me a cron script that had been setup (incorrectly) to reset nginx when certain events occurred, which was the cause of the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows host will refuse connections when the backlog queue is full. Solution: speed up the accept loop or increase the backlog.

And of course any host will refuse connections to a port that isn't in LISTENING state.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error when your nginx connections are all utilized. You need to optimize nginx configuration for maximizing this .  You need to optimize values for `worker_processes` and `worker_connections`.
Following turtorial will help You in optimizing it.
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/optimization/